# DataTemplate not able to resolve DataType prefix data

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, datatemplate, uwp

[image: Left Image is the error and the right one is a Microsoft example]

I'm trying to implement *ListView* in UWP using Window's sample code.

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle >
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:GroupInfoList">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}" 
                                   Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
```

The line  -

> DataTemplate x:DataType="data:GroupInfoList"

Is giving me error, shown in the left image, When creating models am I suppose to create them differently.It says

> The namespace prefix "data" is not defined.

Is it a namespace that I need to include?

Comment: Personally I gave up on compiled bindings and just used normal bindings. It seems to be a design time error, as I've got it to compile before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just had the same issue, this page was copied/pasted from the Universal ListView sample.

The pasted page was full of bad characters, such as line feeds etc. I cleaned the page by removing lines and line feeds around the data template and all is fine.

Answer (score 5):

In your case `data:GroupInfoList` is the type `GroupInfoList` in the namespace mapping `data`.
You have to define the namespace mapping before you can use it.

In the `Page` element of `SimpleListViewSample` you should have something like this:

```
<Page
    x:Class="HermantsListV2.Sample.SimpleListViewSample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:data="HermantsListV2.Model">
...
```

(Notice the `xmlns:data="HermantsListV2.Model` mapping.)

Just replace the namespaces in the example above with the right ones from your project and it should work.

Comment: Make's sense to work but it doesn't > Error Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error  The name "Contact" does not exist in the namespace "HermantsListV2.Model". Hemant's List V2 C:\Users\webonise\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hemant's List V2\Hemant's List V2\Sample\SimpleListViewSample.xaml 17

Comment: Where as it is present there it-self.

Comment: I cleaned and rebuild the solutions.Still not working!

Comment: So then please check the following: a) Are the classes you want to bind public? b) Are the namespaces correct (I just used some example namespaces because I don't know your exact namespace names)?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in the **Visual Studio 2015** to solve it just comment that part of the code and run it. after that uncomment it and it will run without any error.

1- Comment this part of the code:

```
<!--<DataTemplate x:DataType="data:GroupInfoList">
          <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}" 
                     Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
 </DataTemplate>-->
```

2- run your app.

3- uncomment this part of code:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="data:GroupInfoList">
          <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}" 
                     Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

4- run the app.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get this working sometimes if you cut the code inside your gridview etc then save, build and paste it back. Not sure why, but it fixes it sometimes, maybe VS makes something hidden there.